# Does not display casperjs test cases output on the azure web job in toggle output section

Tags: azure, phantomjs, casperjs, azure-webjobs

Does not display casperjs test cases output on the azure web job in toggle output section.

I have created windows application in visual studio 2013 to run casperjs test cases on local machine(desktop). It runs successfully and display following output

> ```
> >Test file: 4jotTestCases.js
> >
> ># 4Jot Test Cases
> >
> >PASS 4Jot Test Cases (1742 tests)
> >
> >Document width : 1366
> >
> >PASS Login Screen 15inchNotebook 1366 X 768 Resolution.
> >
> >PASS Login homepage title is the one expected
> >
> >PASS Login form is found
> >
> >PASS User Name Field Visible
> >
> >PASS Password Field Visible
> >
> >PASS Submit button visible
> >
> >PASS Add New Goal Button is Visible
> >
> >PASS Find an element matching: button#AddNewGoal
> ```

I have created an azure web job to run the CasperJs test cases for my web application.

It runs successfully and currently display the following toggle output result:

> ```
> >[08/09/2016 15:14:39 > 796fcc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
> >[08/09/2016 15:14:39 > 796fcc: SYS INFO] Job directory change detected:Job file 'Microsoft.Data.OData.xml' timestamp differs between source and working directories.
> >[08/09/2016 15:14:39 > 796fcc: SYS INFO] Run script 'CasperjsAzureWebJob.exe' with script host -'WindowsScriptHost'
> >[08/09/2016 15:14:39 > 796fcc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
> >[08/09/2016 15:14:39 > 796fcc: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success
> ```

Now my question is how can i get the 'CasperJs' test cases output on the azure web job toggle output section?

Comment: What is `'CasperjsAzureWebJob.exe'`? How do you deploy the `CasperJs` to Azure?

Comment: I have deploy the azure web job via visual studio 2013.

Comment: Did you compile the `'CasperjsAzureWebJob.exe'` and then deploy to Azure? Or you are using pure `CasperJs` with its dependencies?

Comment: I have deploy the azure web job via visual studio 2013. First step: I have created "New Azure WebJob Project" in visual studio 2013 and give the name "CasperjsAzureWebJob". You will get this option in your visual studio 2013 after install the azure sdk. Second Step: Once the "Azure WebJob Project" created. I wrote the code to execute the casperjs scripts, build the  "CasperjsAzureWebJob" project and publish it via "Publish as Azure WebJob" option provided in visual studio 2013

Comment: following are the code: static void Main()
        {
                       
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"D:\home\site\repository\CasperJs\Installation\bin\casperjs", @"test D:\home\site\repository\CasperJs\4jotTestCases.js --xunit=4jotTestCases/4jotTesting.xml");
                                                          
        }

Comment: CasperjsAzureWebJob.exe is console application I wrote to invoke phython to run my casperjs script. I hardcoded path to the casperjs as they are located on the cloud server.